# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\xampp\htdocs\sql\conexion.php:5

Tags: php, sql-server

Buenas tardes compañeros estoy haciendo una prueba de conexion con sql server y php pero me da este error

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: could not find driver in C:\xampp\htdocs\sql\conexion.php:5 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\sql\conexion.php(5): PDO->__construct('sqlsrv:server=D...', 'root', Object(SensitiveParameterValue)) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\sql\conexion.php on line 5

ya descargue los drivers y los puse en la carpeta de extensiones de php y puse las extensiones en el archivo de configuración de php

este es el código donde intento conectarme a la bd

```
<?php

#para la conexion con sql server y php 

$conexion = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=DESKTOP-OTBPRV3;database=baselibro","root","1234");

$consulta= $conexion->prepare("SELECT * FROM Autor");

$consulta->execute(); 

$datos= $consulta->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

var_dump($datos); 

?>
```

tengo instalado php 8.2
y en el archivo de configuraciones lo tengo así.

[image: aquí active algunas extensiones como las pdo y añadí las extensiones para sql server]

¿me podría ayudar?
cualquier ayuda será bien recibida. :) por favor y muchas gracias.

Comment: Estas intentando conectar con un controlador diseñado para php 8.1. No hay controlador estable para 8.2, pero puedes intentar con la [versión beta](https://github.com/microsoft/msphpsql/releases/tag/v5.11.0-beta1) aún en desarrollo, que si soporta 8.2. También usa la versión adecuada dependiendo de tu interprete de PHP (TS o NTS).

Answer (score 0):

para los que también intenten conectar sql server con php. Es muy importante recalcar que AUN no hay un driver para php en su version 8.2 por lo que por mas que intenten usar el driver para 8.1 (que es la más reciente) no funcionará por que las versiones son distintas. en mi caso baje de versión de php a php 8.1 para poder así usar los drivers. y así no me dio problemas. espero les sea útil.